# How do I calculate perceived size?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If a $6$ foot tall man was $30$ feet away how tall would he look if i squinted my eyes and put a ruler next to him. Is there a way to calculate this? I've tried looking this up and found that angular size = $2\arctan(g/2r)$. I don't know if the angle that this gives mean can be converted into the heigth the man would look. Is there an equation for this?

Comment: What kind of size do you expect? Angle is the right thing - You might say that it looks like a 2 feet box at a distance of 20 feet or a 1 foot box at a distance of 10 feet or ...

Comment: This is a problem in computer graphics or similar?

Comment: Astronomers use angles to describe how "big" the sun and moon "look".

Comment: I rewrote my question to better explain what i meant. It was 4:00 am when i wrote that so i was kind of tired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have not given the exact details about length of the box. When the box is seen from the top, in the straight on position, it will look like a rectangular plane because the height can't be seen.

I think that you are looking for the angle of view i.e. the solid angle subtended by the box when viewed from the top.

So, let's assume that $l$ is the length & $b$ is the width of the box when seen from the top at a normal distance $d$ from the center of the top rectangular plane  of the box then the solid angle subtended by the box at the eye of the observer is given ([here in details](http://www.academia.edu/8440169/Solid_angle_subtended_by_a_rectangular_plane_at_any_point_in_the_space)) as follows
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{solid angle subtended by rectangle of size}\ l\times b,\ \Omega=4\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{lb}{\sqrt{(l^2+4d^2)(b^2+4d^2)}}\right)}}$$
Thus if we know the value of angular size i.e. solid angle $\Omega$ & any two of $l$, $b$ & $d$ then we can easily calculate third unknown side of the box when viewed from the top in a straight-on-position.